# Git Automation - Default Branches

Tags: git, automation, branch

I'm trying to setup some 'Global Defaults' when our team gets started on new projects.
Ideally I'd like to configure some sort of script to accomplish the following:

- New Repository Created -> Automatically create specific branches (i.e. develop/release/hotfix/feature/etc.)

Is this possible within Git itself or should it be done using the shell?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be worth looking at git flow.  The `git flow init` command does that.

https://github.com/nvie/gitflow

You might actually be interested in using git flow directly rather than just looking at how it does it, in which case I'd recommend reading this intro to it,

http://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/2010/why-arent-you-using-git-flow/

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for.  Thanks.  Now to see how easy it will be to roll into GitExtensions for our Windows guys.